# my arduino uno board is not working

Tags: arduino-uno

at once, when i connect arduino uno to my computer, my computer shuts down, after that i cannot upload programs to my computer,the board is not working but the led is ON. Before this, i upload programs 4 to 5 times continuously. i upload program with no physical connections in arduino except motor shield which is also not connected to anything.
i used three boards, all of them got damaged.

my computer's USB port and USB cable is in good codition.
i already updated my drivers.

computer spec: dell inspiron 15 3567
               windows10 x64 bit

Comment: Real Arduinos, or cheap chinese knockoffs?

Comment: Did you try without the shield connected? I think upload doesn't work when something is connected to D0, no idea if this applies to ohter pins too. When you try to upload, what error do you get? Enable verbose output during upload in the preferences.

Answer (score 2):

Computer shutting down is often an indication that excess power is being drawn.
If you measure  between +5 and Gnd on the unpowered board with a meter set for resistance, do you get a reading in the 5Kohm range? Or something much lower? Much lower would be bad.